# Add multiple vectors concurrently in cuda

Tags: cuda, gpu

I want to design a kernel to add a matrix row pairs concurrently, but I don't know how to accomplish it.

For example, I have a data matrix, which size is (512, 1024), and I want to add its row pairs(row1+row2, row3+row4,...,row511+row512) at same time.

The reason I’m considering doing this is just for saving time.

Could you give me some advice?
Thanks!

Comment: This is almost like a vectorAdd.  It should only require a bit of tweaking of index calculations to the CUDA `vectorAdd` sample code, to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may be useful:

```
const int width = 1024;
const int rows = 512;
template <typename T>
__global__ void row_add(const T * __restrict__ din, T * __restrict__ dout){
  int idx = width*2*blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
  if (dout == din)
    dout[idx] += dout[idx+width];
  else
    dout[idx-blockIdx.x*width] = din[idx]+din[idx+width];
}
```

It depends on the width dimension being 1024 or less.  You would launch it like this:

```
row_add<<<rows/2, width>>>(d_in, d_out);
```

If you pass it different pointers for `d_in` and `d_out`, it will assume you want the output written contiguously to a separate array.  If you pass it the same pointer for `d_in` and `d_out`, it will assume you want the results of row 0+1 written to row 0, the results of row 2+3 written to row 2, and so on.

The rows dimension has to be an even number, obviously from your problem statement (adding rows pairwise).

coded in browser, not tested, may contain bugs